# what is the purpose of default-web-module attribute in host tag in standalone.xml file of wildfly 9?

Tags: java, xml, wildfly, wildfly-8, hosts

am working on wildfly,

in standalone.xml file i have configured hosts as
 
**standalone.xml :**

```
<host name="wildflyhost1" alias="test.test1.com" default-web-module="test1.war"/>
<host name="wildflyhost2" alias="test.test2.com" default-web-module="test2.war"/>
```

My Question is,
 default-web-module="test2.war" is mandatory ?
what happens when the war file is not available in server deployments ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> default-web-module="test2.war" is mandatory ?

No it is not mandatory, it defaults to ROOT.war if not configured.
This config option allows you to deploy application "test2.war" to "/" context as by default and by servlet spec it would get bound to /test2

> what happens when the war file is not available in server deployments ?

Noting, it works either way, it just tells server if it finds deployment by this name to bound it to "/" context.